# Write a C++ program that finds and lists all possible correct credit card numbers according to the Luhn algorithm

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I need to **print all possible correct credit card numbers according to the Luhn algorithm**, and I did like a 16 for loops nested inside each other,
I was wondering if there is a way to make my code shorter?
Here is my code:

this is for index 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16 It takes the number and multiply it by 2. and after that it takes the sum of the individual numbers; lets say index 0 is 6 it takes 6*2=12 and sums 1+ 2

```
int dbl(int x) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (x !=0)
    {
        sum += x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

void bruh(int x, int y) {
    
    x += (dbl(2 * y));
}
```

This is my loops:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l <= 9; l++)
                {
                    for (int m = 0; m <= 9; m++)
                    {
                        for (int n = 0; n <= 9; n++)
                        {
                            for (int o = 0; o <= 9; o++)
                            {
                                for (int p = 0; p <= 9; p++)
                                {
                                    for (int q = 0; q <= 9; q++)
                                    {
                                        for (int r = 0; r <=9; r++)
                                        {
                                            for (int s = 0; s <= 9; s++)
                                            {
                                                for (int u = 0; u <= 9; u++)
                                                {
                                                    for (int v = 0; v <= 9; v++)
                                                    {
                                                        for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++)
                                                        {
                                                            for (int w = 0; w <= 9; w++)
                                                            {
                                                                for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++)
                                                                {
                                                                    int dbles = 0, sngls =0;
                                                                    bruh(dbles, i);
                                                                    sngls += j;
                                                                    bruh(dbles, k);
                                                                    sngls += l;

                                                                    bruh(dbles, m);
                                                                    sngls += n;
                                                                    bruh(dbles, o);
                                                                    sngls += p;

                                                                    bruh(dbles, q);
                                                                    sngls += r;
                                                                    bruh(dbles, s);
                                                                    sngls += u;

                                                                    bruh(dbles, v);
                                                                    sngls += x;
                                                                    bruh(dbles, w);
                                                                    sngls += y;
                                                                    if (dbles+sngls%10==0)
                                                                    {
                                                                        cout << "Valid Number: " << i << j << k << l << m << n << o << p << q << r << s << u << v << x << w << y << endl;
                                                                        cout << "---------------" << endl;
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program works fine(added a break statement to stop after 100th cc to check if it runs, And it dose), I just want to know if there is away to **make my code shorter**

Comment: You never actually use the value returned by `bruh`.

Comment: my bad that was the old one I just added the one I made

Comment: Because `bruh` accepts its arguments by value and returns nothing it has no effect on any code outside it. You could remove all calls to it and not change the behavior of your program.

Comment: Do you have an estimate of how many lines your program will print?

Comment: I kept it running for 2 or 3 m and it was still printing,

Comment: Can I change `bruh` lines to dbl(2*i) and it will be the same ?

Comment: Re: `I kept it running for 2 or 3 m and it was still printing` - is `m` a minute or a month? :)

Comment: its in minutes not months

Comment: Credit card number consists of 15 digits + 1 control. So, there are 10^15 possible numbers. Printing all of them will take *a lot* of time. I would store individual digits (15 of them) in an array and implement an increment function for the number stored in that array, then calculate checksum and just append it to the number. No reason to generate all 16 and test them, this wastes 90% of computation resources.

Comment: @M.W Let's do some math. All combinations of first 15 digits are valid, as only the last digits is a "checksum". so that is ~1,000,000,000,000,000 values. Say you can print 1,000 per second (I doubt that); then it will take 1,000,000,000,000 seconds, or 11,574,074 days, or over 30,000 years.

Comment: sorry guys I should have been more clearer. I don't need to like print numbers and have them by my side to check on them. I know this program takes like an infinite amount of time to  end. I just need a program that dose that to test my coding skills I have just started my learning journey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will be much shorter and easier to read:

```
#include <string>

void increment(std::string& s) {
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (s[i] != '9') {
            s[i]++;
            return;
        }
        s[i] = '0';
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "0000000000000000";
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 1'000'000'000'000'000; ++i) {
        // do your check with s[0]..s[15]
        increment(s);
    }
}
```

NOTE: this does pretty much what you tried to do in your code.

You can take n0rd's suggestion and loop through 15 digit numbers, calculating the checksum and appending it to the end. In that case you'd only need 3,000 years instead of 30,000 :)